# SwiftUI Previews struct "Missing argument for parameter 'text' in call"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have wrapped a custom UIView inside a SwiftUI View and the Preview struct is giving me problems:

```
struct ContentView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    ....
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some UIViewRepresentable {
        ContentView() // This is the offending line. It wants to change it to:
                      // ContentView(text: <#Binding<String>#>)
    }
}
```

What can I do to get this to work right? Why is it asking for a text argument?

Thanks!

Comment: did you added variables to your view?

Comment: The compiler is easily confused and will start generating errors and suggested fixed that are not correct. When this happens to me, I start disabling chunks of code to isolate the actual problem. It is usually a missing comma, variable name or bracket in some other location.

Comment: Yes, @NicolasElPapu. I did add variables. :)

Comment: @Lester can you try passing your variable/s as arguments to the ContentView() initializer?

Comment: I am not familiar with that concept. I could declare them in an initializer, but I have never seen them passed through it. I am a bit embarassed.

Comment: Try: ContentView(text: "hello")

Comment: Actually it says: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'

Comment: That fixed it. I needed to use a @State variable. Thank you.